# Parse nested XML using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I have an xml of the below format. There are 2 parts of xml (job_type = "REQUESTED" and job_type = "RECOMMENDED"); I want to parse only the values from the Requested block.
Also in the Applicants tag there are two types of Application (type = "PB" and type = "CB")

I want to parse the result into a csv in the below format

```
id , social_security_number (where type = "PB"), first_name(where type = "PB"), city(where type = "PB" and item_code="CURRENT"), state_code_id(where type = "PB" and item_code="CURRENT"), com(where item_code="PEMAIL" and type ="PB"), social_security_number (where type = "CB"), first_name(where type = "CB"), city(where type = "CB" and item_code="CURRENT"), state_code_id(where type = "CB" and item_code="CURRENT"), com(where item_code="PEMAIL" and type ="CB")
```

Eg Result :

```
2407132 ,999999999, Thomas, Portland, MI, edison@gmail.com, 123456789, Mary, BarHarBor, MI, mary@gmail.com

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<JobApplications xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="2407132" bundle_id="2407132" version="1.0">
<JobApplication job_type="REQUESTED" request_date="2014-08-02T12:26:00.0000000">
<JobApplicationStates>
<JobApplicationState type="USEDCL" payment_call_flag="False">
<Applicants>
<Applicant social_security_number="999999999" type="PB" date_of_birth="1972-10-01T00:00:00.0000000" first_name="Thomas" last_name="Edison">
<Addresses>
<Address city="Portland" state_code_id="MI" country_code="USA" postal_code="12345" item_code="CURRENT" street_number="6297" street="LAKE ARBOR" />
<Address item_code="PREVIOUS" />
</Addresses>
<Communications>
<Communication item_code="PEMAIL" com="edison@gmail.com" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="HOME" com="(123)-456-7890" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="OTHER" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="WORK" com="(100)-200-3000" contact_type="CU"/>
</Communications>
</Applicant>
<Applicant social_security_number="123456789" type="CB" date_of_birth="1976-10-01T00:00:00.0000000" first_name="Mary" last_name="Edison">
<Addresses>
<Address city="BarHarBor" state_code_id="MI" country_code="USA" postal_code="12345" item_code="CURRENT" street_number="6297" street="LAKE ARBOR" />
<Address item_code="PREVIOUS" />
</Addresses>
<Communications>
<Communication item_code="PEMAIL" com="mary@gmail.com" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="HOME" com="(999)-456-7890" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="OTHER" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="WORK" com="(300)-200-3000" contact_type="CU"/>
</Communications>
</Applicant>
</Applicants> 
</JobApplicationState>
</JobApplicationStates>
</JobApplication>
<JobApplication job_type="RECOMMENDED" request_date="2014-08-02T12:26:00.0000000">
<JobApplicationStates>
<JobApplicationState type="USEDCL" payment_call_flag="False">
<Applicants>
<Applicant social_security_number="999999999" type="PB" date_of_birth="1972-10-01T00:00:00.0000000" first_name="Thomas" last_name="Edison">
<Addresses>
<Address city="Portland" state_code_id="MI" country_code="USA" postal_code="12345" item_code="CURRENT" street_number="6297" street="LAKE ARBOR" />
<Address item_code="PREVIOUS" />
</Addresses>
<Communications>
<Communication item_code="PEMAIL" com="edison@gmail.com" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="HOME" com="(123)-456-7890" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="OTHER" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="WORK" com="(100)-200-3000" contact_type="CU"/>
</Communications>
</Applicant>
<Applicant social_security_number="123456789" type="CB" date_of_birth="1976-10-01T00:00:00.0000000" first_name="Mary" last_name="Edison">
<Addresses>
<Address city="BarHarBor" state_code_id="MI" country_code="USA" postal_code="12345" item_code="CURRENT" street_number="6297" street="LAKE ARBOR" />
<Address item_code="PREVIOUS" />
</Addresses>
<Communications>
<Communication item_code="PEMAIL" com="mary@gmail.com" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="HOME" com="(999)-456-7890" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="OTHER" contact_type="CU"/>
<Communication item_code="WORK" com="(300)-200-3000" contact_type="CU"/>
</Communications>
</Applicant>
</Applicants> 
</JobApplicationState>
</JobApplicationStates>
</JobApplication>
```

Any pointers how to parse in the required format using XDocument ? I have millions of xmls to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can often flatten xml file out so it is easier to put into a database and read.  In your case I think this is best method.  See code below.  I did not think it is a good idea to complicate the parsing method by only parsing certain items when the datatable result can be filtered after the parsing is completed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Job Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Request Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Job State Type",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Payment Call Flag", typeof(Boolean));
            dt.Columns.Add("SSN", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Appliacant Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DOB", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));

            dt.Columns.Add("City", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("State", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Postal Code", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Street Number", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Street", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Email", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Home Phone", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Other", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Work Phone", typeof(string));


            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement jobApplications = doc.Root;
            int id = (int)jobApplications.Attribute("id");

            foreach (XElement jobApplication in jobApplications.Elements("JobApplication"))
            {
                string job_type = (string)jobApplication.Attribute("job_type");
                DateTime request_date = (DateTime)jobApplication.Attribute("request_date");
                string job_state_type = (string)jobApplication.Descendants("JobApplicationState").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("type");
                Boolean payment_call_flag = (Boolean)jobApplication.Descendants("JobApplicationState").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("payment_call_flag");

                foreach (XElement applicant in jobApplication.Descendants("Applicant"))
                {
                    string social_security_number = (string)applicant.Attribute("social_security_number");
                    string applicant_type = (string)applicant.Attribute("type");
                    DateTime date_of_birth = (DateTime)applicant.Attribute("date_of_birth");
                    string first_name = (string)applicant.Attribute("first_name");
                    string last_name = (string)applicant.Attribute("last_name");


                    XElement address = applicant.Descendants("Address").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("item_code") == "CURRENT").FirstOrDefault();
                    string city = (string)address.Attribute("city");
                    string state = (string)address.Attribute("state_code_id");
                    string country = (string)address.Attribute("country_code");
                    string postal_code = (string)address.Attribute("postal_code");
                    string street_number = (string)address.Attribute("street_number");
                    string street = (string)address.Attribute("street");

                    XElement communications = applicant.Descendants("Communications").FirstOrDefault();
                    string email = communications.Elements().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("item_code") == "PEMAIL").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("com")).FirstOrDefault();
                    string home_phone = communications.Elements().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("item_code") == "HOME").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("com")).FirstOrDefault();
                    string other = communications.Elements().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("item_code") == "OTHER").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("com")).FirstOrDefault();
                    string work_phone = communications.Elements().Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("item_code") == "WORK").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("com")).FirstOrDefault();

                    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {
                        id,
                        job_type, request_date, job_state_type, payment_call_flag,
                        social_security_number, applicant_type, date_of_birth, first_name, last_name,
                        city, state, country, postal_code, street_number, street,
                        email, home_phone, other, work_phone
                    });
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tweaked it to get what I want. I basically liked the idea!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you to convert your xml files to csv with few lines of code by using Open source library [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL/)

As xml is structural formatted file, you will need to flatten out in order to produce CSV. With the help of XPath and Cinchoo ETL library, you can produce CSV file quickly.

Sample code below shows how to parse your xml and convert them to csv

```
using (var parser = new ChoXmlReader("sample.xml").WithXPath("JobApplications")
    .WithField("ID", xPath: "@id")
    .WithField("PB_SSN", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='PB']/@social_security_number")
    .WithField("PB_FIRST_NAME", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='PB']/@first_name")
    .WithField("PB_CITY", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='PB']/Addresses/Address[@item_code='CURRENT']/@city")
    .WithField("PB_STATE", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='PB']/Addresses/Address[@item_code='CURRENT']/@state_code_id")
    .WithField("PB_PEMAIL", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='PB']/Communications/Communication[@item_code='PEMAIL']/@com")
    .WithField("CB_SSN", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='CB']/@social_security_number")
    .WithField("CB_FIRST_NAME", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='CB']/@first_name")
    .WithField("CB_CITY", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='CB']/Addresses/Address[@item_code='CURRENT']/@city")
    .WithField("CB_STATE", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='CB']/Addresses/Address[@item_code='CURRENT']/@state_code_id")
    .WithField("CB_PEMAIL", xPath: "/JobApplication[@job_type='REQUESTED']/JobApplicationStates/JobApplicationState/Applicants/Applicant[@type='CB']/Communications/Communication[@item_code='PEMAIL']/@com")
)
{
    using (var writer = new ChoCSVWriter("sample.csv"))
        writer.Write(parser);
}
```

Output:

```
2407132,999999999,Thomas,Portland,MI,edison@gmail.com,123456789,Mary,BarHarBor,MI,mary@gmail.com
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library.